# JSONのエラー`[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)　を解決したい

Tags: ruby

いつもお世話になっています。

現在、OpenWeatherMapのAPIを使って、天気や湿度、そして気温などを出力するプログラムをRubyで作成中です。

参考サイトは
https://qiita.com/nownabe/items/aeac1ce0977be963a740
です。

＜コード＞

```
puts "都市名を入力してください"
name = gets.chomp

API_KEY = "my API KEY"
BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"

require "json"
require "open-uri"

response = open(BASE_URL + "?q=#{name},jp&APPID=#{API_KEY}")
data = JSON.parse(response.read, {symbolize_names: true})
puts data[:list][0][:main][:temp]
puts data[:list][0][:main][:humidity]
puts data[:list][0][:main][:temp_min]
puts data[:list][0][:main][:temp_max]
puts data[:list][0][:weather][:main]
```

＜エラーメセージ＞

```
ex014.rb:16:in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
    from ex014.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

このエラーメッセージによると、おそらく数字の出力には問題がないと思うのですが、"Clear"などの文字列を出力する際に問題があるということだと思うのですが、どう解決すればいいでしょうか？
お知恵をお貸しいただけたら幸いです。

Comment: 参照された記事を眺めてみますと、`data[:list][0][:weather]` は hash ではなく array になっています。ですので、`puts data[:list][0][:weather][0][:main]` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーが出ているのは以下の行です。

```
puts data[:list][0][:weather][:main]
```

data[:list][0][:weather] は配列であるため、整数のインデックスでアクセスする必要がありますそこで :main というシンボル(Symbol)を整数(Integer)に変換しようとして、変換できない内容のエラーが発生しています。

```
`[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

以下のコードで期待する動作となりますでしょうか？

```
puts data[:list][0][:weather][0][:main]
```

また以下のようにして整形したJSONを保存しておくことで、JSONのデータ構造が確認しやすくなると思います。

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)
```